# How to run JAPE rules

Tags: text-mining, gate

Necessary please !
I want to ask about how to run Jape rules in the Gate program,, My documents and rules are for Arabic language ,,

I wrote the rule in note file with .jape extension , and save it in path :

`>> lang Arabic >> resources >> grammar`

,, then what ??!! When I run the application nothing happened !!

and what about the file (all.jape) ?? it is the only file appears from inside GATE program ,, does my new rule appear inside it ?? it does not !

Comment: Your question is absolutely unclear. Please provide more detailed information

Answer (score 0):

Just use the **JAPE Transducer** PR from the ANNIE plugin.

Processing resources -> New -> JAPE Transducer

The picture is bellow :-)

See also the videos here: https://gate.ac.uk/demos/developer-videos/
and some other on the internet...

[image: How to create GATE JAPE Transducer]

Comment: I use the "Arabic grammar" in : ready made application >> ِArabic >> Arabic IE system ..

Comment: @MaaliElhaj JAPE Transducer can run any jape grammar, even from Arabic IE system, just setup the grammar url in the config dialog.

Comment: OK thank you so much. but can you tell me what is the difference between these tow action :  JAPE Transducer that you show me , and Arabic grammar in IE system ??
,, in another way, why Gate has more than one of JAPE processor  while that one (witch you show) is enough to run any JAPE grammar ؟؟

Comment: @MaaliElhaj: The command `ready made application >> ِArabic >> Arabic IE system` is a shortcut for creating several processing resources at once. It includes the same JAPE Transducer, which you can load separately (as I have shown) as well.

Comment: Thank u so much for answering ..But, if you tracing : the file (all.jape) which shows the jape rules in Arabic grammar is in different path, it is in : C:\Program Files\GATE_Developer_8.1\plugins\Lang_Arabic\resources\inferred-grammar . but file all.jape which appears in jape transducer have path : C:\Program Files\GATE_Developer_8.1\plugins\Lang_Arabic\resources\grammar .. They had different paths they are not the same !!!

Comment: @MaaliElhaj Yes, I can also see the two versions (`gramm‌​ar` and `infer‌​red-grammar`). You can load whatever version you like. But I don't know  the diffrence, nor any details about hese grammars... Checkout the docs: https://gate.ac.uk/userguide/sec:misc-creole:language-plugins:arabic

Comment: thank u so much . OK I want to ask you about JAPE rules themselves , when I write the rule based on POS tag , which features I should use (like category - kind ...) I mean is there specific features or what ??

Comment: @MaaliElhaj each POS tagger can use different feature names, but `category` is used very often e.g. by the ANNIE POS tagger https://gate.ac.uk/sale/tao/splitch6.html#sec:annie:tagger